# Passing Classes/Components with properties in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm new to CF, coming from a .NET background. I'm wondering what the best practice type thing would be for the following situation.

Say I have a component, `car.cfc` and I have a function inside this component that requires the properties:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfproperty name="Name" />
    <cfproperty name="Model" />
    <cfproperty name="Make" />

    <cffunction name="BuildCarXML">
        <cfargument name="car" type="car" />
        <cfsavecontent variable="xmlCar">
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <car>
               <name>#arguments.car.Name#</name>
            </car>
        </cfsavecontent>
        <cfreturn xmlCar />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Finally, i call this function from a cfm page:

```
<cfscript>
    cfcCar = CreateObject("car");
    cfcCar.Name="AU";
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#cfcCar.BuildCarXML(cfcCar)#">
```

My question is, is this the correct/best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<cfcomponent accessor="true">
    <cfproperty name="name" />
    <cfproperty name="model" />
    <cfproperty name="make" />

    <cffunction name="BuildCarXML" output="false">
        <cfsavecontent variable="local.xmlCar">
            <cfoutput><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <car>
               <name>#variables.name#</name>
            </car></cfoutput>
        </cfsavecontent>
        <cfreturn xmlCar />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Finally, u call this function from a cfm page:

```
<cfscript>
    cfcCar = new Car();
    cfcCar.setName("AU");
    writeDump(cfcCar.BuildCarXML());
</cfscript>
```

Comment: You may look into using `<cfxml>` if you want to also validate the xml u're building is really valid xml.

Comment: I was using cfxml, and i'm about to open another question about it vs savecontent.

Comment: well, with `<cfxml>` and `toString()` you're constructing an xml object in CF.  So it'd be easier if you want to do `xmlsearch()` later, or manipulate it through the API.  However, your current `<cfsavecontent>` way would be faster, but watch out for unexpected whitespaces, especially in the beginning that may break some xml parser.

Comment: I'm trying to build an xml file, but it's split into multiple functions. see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617998/cfxml-vs-cfsavecontent-unable-to-build-xml-using-cfxml Thanks