# cfxml vs cfsavecontent - unable to build xml using cfxml

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying build a custom XML file and splitting the building into separate functions, but I'm having trouble doing this with cfxml. This example is obviously simplified.

This works fine:

```
<cfcomponent accessors="true">
    <cfproperty name="Name" />
    <cfproperty name="Model" />
    <cfproperty name="Make" />

    <cffunction name="BuildCarXML" output="false">
        <cfsavecontent variable="xmlCar">
            <cfoutput>
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <car>
               <name>#variables.Name#</name>
               #AddMakeElement()#
            </car>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfsavecontent>
        <cfreturn xmlCar />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="AddMakeElement">
        <cfsavecontent variable="xmlMake">
            <cfoutput>
                <make>Something</make>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfsavecontent>
        <cfreturn xmlMake />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

But this produces an XML string with spaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <car> <name>Ferrari</name> <make>Something</make> </car>
```

If I use `cfxml`, or even do an `XMLParse()` on the cfreturn of BuildCarXML, i get the following error:

```
An error occured while Parsing an XML document.

The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

Is it possible to do this using cfxml?

Comment: FYI, watch out for scoping issue. `variable="local.xmlMake"` would be much safer, otherwise `xmlMake` will be leaked into the CFC's variables scope and not thread-safe.

Comment: Oh. I wasn't aware of this. I though variables inside a function are only within the scope of that function

Comment: yes, welcome to CF. :)  Sorry, I know, we are embarrassed too.

Comment: lol thanks. So is local a key/reserved word for this sort of stuff or can you use anything to specify the scope?

Comment: Ya. Use local-dot to reference local scope. there are many scopes in CF. Look up the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `AddMakeElement()`, if you use `<cfxml>` and `toString()`, the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <make>Something</make>
```

Therefore it couldn't be embedded into your `xmlCar`.  So for `AddMakeElement()`, keep using `<cfsavecontent>`, or just `return "<make>Something</make>"`.

Comment: Ahh. right. Yeah, i was using cfxml in both functions. So obvious now! lol. thanks